# JQuery slider missing active state when clicking arrows

Tags: jquery, slider, carousel, gsap

I have a slider that works fine but to work better should have an active class which I found difficult to add.

Slider should start on the center of the viewport/screen and have an active state each time I click the arrow next and prev.

what's the best way approach?

I hope it makes sense.
I will provide both demos.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidesitua/89b7edh0/14/)

```js
var s = $('.slider'),
  sWrapper = s.find('.slider-wrapper'),
  sItem = s.find('.slide'),
  btn = s.find('.slider-link'),
  sWidth = sItem.width(),
  sCount = sItem.length,

  slide_title = s.find('.slide-title'),
  slide_text = s.find('.slide-text'),
  slide_image = s.find('.slide-content img'),
  sTotalWidth = sCount * sWidth;

sWrapper.css('width', sTotalWidth);
sWrapper.css('width', sTotalWidth);

btn.on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if ($(this).hasClass('next')) {


    (clickCount < (sCount - 1)) ? clickCount++ : clickCount = 0;
  } else if ($(this).hasClass('prev')) {

    (clickCount > 0) ? clickCount-- : (clickCount = sCount - 1);

  }
  TweenMax.to(sWrapper, 0.4, {
    x: '-' + (sWidth * clickCount)
  })


  //CONTENT ANIMATIONS

  var fromProperties = {
    autoAlpha: 0,
    x: '-50'
  };
  var toProperties = {
    autoAlpha: 0.8,
    x: '0',
    y: '0'
  };

  TweenLite.fromTo(slide_image, 1, {
    autoAlpha: 0,
    x: '40'
  }, {
    autoAlpha: 1,
    x: '0'
  });
  TweenLite.fromTo(slide_title, 0.6, fromProperties, toProperties);
  TweenLite.fromTo(slide_text, 0.8, fromProperties, toProperties);
});

var clickCount = 0;
```

```css
.slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0vw 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.slider-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.slide {
  box-shadow: 0 50px 60px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin-right: 6rem;
  position: relative;
}

.slider-wrapper {
  margin: 5vw 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.slide-content {
  width: 25vw;
  padding: 8rem;
}

.slide-title {
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}

img {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 4rem auto;
}

.slide-text {
  padding-bottom: 4vw;
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
}

.last {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
}

.slide-nav {
  margin-left: 64vw;
  margin-top: -5.5vw;
}

div.overlay-blue {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: 0.5s ease all;
}

div.overlay-blue:hover {
  background-color: rgba(13, 27, 43, 0.5);
}

.arrows {
  width: 3.5vw;
  margin-top: 0vw;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 1.2vw;
  height: 1.2vw;
  background: transparent;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  border-top: 0.15vw solid blue;
  border-left: 0.15vw solid blue;
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: transparent;
  bottom: 100px;
}

.arrow:hover {
  border-color: blue;
  border-width: 0.25vw;
}

.arrow:before {
  display: block;
  height: 200%;
  width: 200%;
  margin-left: -50%;
  margin-top: -50%;
  content: "";
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.arrow.prev {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  left: 0;
}

.arrow.next {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider">

  <div class="slider-wrapper flex">

    <div class="slide flex">
      <div class="slide-content">
        <h3 class="slide-title">Optimize</h3>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100" class="monitor">
        <p class="slide-text">Optimize supply chain transparency and enterprise connectivity</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide flex">
      <div class="slide-content">
        <h3 class="slide-title">Extend</h3>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100" class="extend">
        <p class="slide-text">Increase machine to machine connectivity and collaboration</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide flex">

      <div class="slide-content">
        <h3 class="slide-title">Transform</h3>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100" class="transform">
        <p class="slide-text">Enable a truly modular production process</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide flex">
      <div class="slide-content last">
        <ul>
          <li>Vehicles as fully connected digital twin </li>
          <li>Self-awereness, intelligent data exchange</li>
          <li>Continuos closed-loop feedback</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="arrows">
    <a href="#" title="Previous" class="arrow slider-link prev"></a>
    <a href="#" title="Next" class="arrow slider-link next"></a>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean "an active state each time I click the arrow next and prev". Do you mean adding the class only while it's animating?

Comment: I was trying to add a class to the tile while I'm sliding, so, each time I'm clicking next and prev a Tile has an active state.

Comment: I think I've done it myself 
http://jsfiddle.net/davidesitua/89b7edh0/41/